# Can i call an controller action with POST-params from another controller as method?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I've a controller and some actions within. Am i able to call these actions as methods from another controller as if i would call this action with post params?

I'm using the grails paypal plugin and it has an action called "buy". I don't want the user to POST the product-data and information to the buy-action. I already know the things the user wants to buy and i want to call the buy-action within my Controller as i would call a normal method and then i want to redirect the user to paypal (to the url, the buy action returns).

I'm using grails 2.0 and newest paypal plugin.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. You can tell from action A to chain to action B. 
But this is not calling it as a method, this will redirect the call to action B, you will not be anymore in action A's scope.

Maybe you can implement your action in a `service`. Then you can call it as you like from your controller's action

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, You can redirect your action to another action which belongs to other controller.

you can use redirect method for that.

```
"redirect(controller: 'abc', action: 'actionName', params: 'params')"
```

Comment: you can redirect to that action after processing again you can redirect from that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [chain(...)](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/chain.html).

Chain:

> Uses flash storage to implicitly retain the model following an HTTP
>   redirect from one action to another.

Comment: If the model doesn't need to be preserved, I'd use `forward` instead of `chain` since it redirects internally rather than doing another HTTP round trip.

Comment: Yes, forward is the next step :-)

Comment: So i can do something like this? PayPalController.buy(params) ?